# How to get certain value from a hashmap inside an object which is a value of another hashmap?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, xml-rpc

Let's say data structure looks something like this in debugger (returned from XML-RPC call):

```
map HashMap
 |- 0 HashMap$HashMapEntry
    |-  key "records"
        value Object[130] // 130 Objects here 
         |- 100 HashMap // Object number 100
             |- 0 HashMap$HashMapEntry
                |-  key "uid"
                    value "420"
```

Is there an easy way how to get let's say value of "uid"? (Should return `420`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
(Integer)((HashMap)((Object[])map.get("records"))[100]).get("uid")
```

Comment: a small correction (Integer)((HashMap)((Object[])map.get("records"))[100]).get("uid")...... in type cast, there is no need to mention length.